# How to map over data that `.find()` returns?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple function:

```
const oldUsers = Users.find(
   {
      isReminded: false,
      creationDate: {
         "$lt": new Date(Date.now() - thirtyDays),
      },
   },
);
```

and then:

```
export const notifyOldUsers = () => 
   Array.isArray(oldUsers) ? oldUsers.map(async(user, i) => {
      await Users.updateOne({ _id: user._id }, { "$set": { isReminded: true }});

      await transporter.sendMail(sendMail));
   }) : [];
};
```

But the problem is that `oldUsers` returns **object**, and if I `console.log` it, its a complicated `Query` object.

**Question**: How to to properly loop over the data, which `.find()` produces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `Users.find()` is an async operation, so `oldUsers` is always going to be undefined. You need to `await` it (if you weren't using promises you'd have to use a callback).

```
const oldUsers = await Users.find(...)
```

Second, your `notifyOldUsers` function is not async, so it runs the mapping function, but exits immediately, not waiting for the mapped async operations to finish.

Typically, when mapping async operations, you should use a `Promise.all()` to collect all the promises returned by the callback function and wait for them all to resolve.

```
export const notifyOldUsers = async () => {
  const promises = oldUsers.map(async (user) => {
    await Users.updateOne({ _id: user._id }, { "$set": { isReminded: true }})
    await transporter.sendMail(sendMail))
  })

  return Promise.all(promises)
}
```

I've intentionally split up the mapping from the `Promise.all()` to illustrate the map of promises being returned. This can be further optimized to the following.

```
export const async notifyOldUsers = async () => {
  return Promise.all( oldUsers.map(async (user) => {
    await Users.updateOne({ _id: user._id }, { "$set": { isReminded: true }})
    await transporter.sendMail(sendMail))
  }) )
}
```

In both cases, this async function will return a new promise who's value will be an array containing the results of the entire map.

Comment: I believe it should be `export const notifyOldUsers = async () =>`

Comment: No, I'm doing an explicit `return`, not a single line fat arrow function.

Comment: That's weird, coz my TS compiler fails if the `async` keyword is before func name

Comment: Oh my mistake, I thought you were talking about the `{` at the end of the line, which I added. I've corrected it.

Comment: Now I got error, that `.map()` is not a function. Seems like still `oldUsers` is not an array

Comment: That's because your `Users.find()` is async and hasn't finished returning any results yet. You need to await it. I've updated my answer to include that.

Comment: Thank you!, works perfectly. Okey - almost, coz im getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: undefined is not a function`, but I will probably ask for help in separate question

Comment: That's because you're not handling errors. Use the debugger. At this point, you're on your own.